# How to move Google Drive Backup folder from one PC to another?

Tags: windows-10, backup, google-sync, google-backup-and-sync

I have a folder on my current PC that I regularly download lots of pdfs, etc to. This folder is backed up and synced through the 'Backup and Sync' desktop client of Google Drive to my account.

I want to change my PC. I don't want to spend data downloading the folder from Drive to my other PC when I can manually copy and paste it via a pen drive.
I wanted to know how do I set up Google Backup and Sync for the same folder on my other PC without allowing Google to change the location.

Setting up backup on the other PC makes google create a backup for a new device in my Drive account. How do I prevent this ?

Thank you.

Comment: It should be as simply as copying the contents of the folder being synchronized on the source PC to the flash drive and then copying contents of the flash drive to the folder being synchronized on the designation PC.

Comment: @Ramhound My question isn't to know how to transfer the files. I wanted to know how to set up Google Backup and sync on the second PC such that the sync is now not done to a new location altogether.

Comment: @Ramhound Google backup and sync will create a fresh new backup for my new device and start reuploading all those files in the new device backup. When they are already there because of my backup from my previous PC. I want to avoid this. I want my files on the second PC to sync to the same location. How do I do this ?